# A function to create Pairwise Combinations of all sequences from alignment file type in PYTHON

Tags: list, function, file, alignment, pairwise

so I've recently started a project about sequence alignment, and have used been using the standalone software programme 'MAFFT' to align some BRCA1 sequences (via. command-line)

I need to create a function which will produce all the pairwise combinations from aln files that I have produced using MAFFT. However I've been told that hard coding the alignments is not good practice e.g. `first_alignment=align[0], second_alignment=align[1]`.

I've parsed the aln files using this code:

```
from Bio import AlignIO

align = AlignIO.read(aln_1, "clustal")
print(align)

align = AlignIO.read(aln_2, "clustal")
print(align)
```

[image: See this picture for output of AlignIO]

Now I need a function to produced all the possible pairwise combinations, so that I can compare sequences and look for transitions/transversions, indels/substitutions, SNPs, or any biological significance.

Would appreciate the help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each of the alignments like shown on the official [biopython](https://biopython.org/wiki/AlignIO) site:

```
for record in alignment :
    print(record.seq + " " + record.id)
```

To get both record you can add a inner loop like:

```
align1 = AlignIO.read(aln_1, "clustal")
align2 = AlignIO.read(aln_2, "clustal")

for record1 in alignment1 :
    for record2 in alignment2:
        # do comparison here
```

For the combination the [pairwise module](https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.pairwise2-module.html), I think has what you are looking for.

An example from the page is:

```
from Bio import pairwise2
alignments = pairwise2.align.globalxx("ACCGT", "ACG")
```

You can adjust that and pass as arguments for gloablxx the two records (inside the double loop) like:

```
alignments = pairwise2.align.globalxx(record1, record2)
```

Hope that is what you are looking for! :)

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful!

Comment: Now I need to think about a function to automate the pairwise comparisons